# How can I automatically have old e-mails deleted in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email, delete

There is a nice feature in Thunderbird which lets you have your old e-mails, say those that are older than 30 days, deleted automatically. This feature (or some workaround) would be nice to have in Evolution, too. Is there anything like that in Evolution or any plugin?
It would save disk space and a lot of loading time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to create a filter: *Edit → Message Filters → Add*

- Condition: *Date received is 30 day ago*
- Action: *Delete*

This filter is never applied automatically, since evolution only check filters on new mails, but you can run it manually by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

Remember to expunge the folder (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) to permanently remove those messages.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the folder, select 'AutoArchive', Check 'Archive this folder' and select 'Delete old messages'